# Adding form data into ics.js file

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have been tinkering around with https://github.com/nwcell/ics.js code to create a downloadable ics file.

However, I need to input data into a form and have that populate the proper variable (title, place, start date, end date).

I can not seem to get the ics.js to pull the values from the from with the document.getElementId method - any suggestions?

Thanks. Sample page can be found here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25536938/FOIL%20Reminder%20Form%20Downloadable%20File.html

```
<html><head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgithub.com/nwcell/ics.js/master/ics.deps.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 <fieldset>
        <legend>Select FOIL Owner</legend>

         Handler: <p>
            <select name="category">

                <option value="Ronald"> Ronald </option>
                <option value="Thomas">Thomas</option>
                <option value="Elizabeth">Elizabeth</option>

            </select>

        </p>

    </fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <legend>FOIL Request Information</legend>
  <form method="post" id="myform" action="javascript:cal_single = ics()" >
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" id="firstname" name = "fname" />
    <br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" id="lastname" name = "lname" />
    <br>
    Email:<br>
    <input type="email" id="email" name = "email" />
    <br>
    Phone:<br>
    <input type="text" id="phone" name = "phone" />
    </form>


<br>


<div>
    Title: <input type="text" name="summary" id = "summary" />
        <br><br>
        Origin Date: <input type = "date" id = "originDate" name = "originDate"/>
        <br>

<br>

<div>

        5 Day Reminder Date: <input type="date" id = "5dayDate" name = "FiveDay" />
        <br>

</div>
<br>

<div>

        20 Day Reminder Date: <input type="date" id = "20dayDate" name = "TwentyDay" />
        <br>

<br>
    Description:
<br>
    <textarea  id="description" name="description"  ></textarea>
    <br>
    Location:
    <br>
    <input value="New York" id="location" name = "location" />


<br><br>
    <div class="wrap">
        <a href="javascript:cal_single.download()" >Single Event</a><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Download" onclick="cal_single.download()" >



    </div>
</form>
<script>

// Demo

var cal_single = ics(); {
  var subject = "Title: " + document.getElementById("summary").value; 

  var foilFirst = "Contact First Name: " + document.getElementById("firstname").value; 
  var foilLast= "Contact Last Name: " + document.getElementById("lastname").value; 
  var foilEmail= "Contact Email: " + document.getElementById("email").value; 
  var foilPhone = "Contact Phone: " + document.getElementById("phone").value; 

  var description = "Description: " + document.getElementById("description").value; 
  var location = "Location: " + document.getElementById("location").value; 

  var originalDate = document.getElementById( "originDate").value;

  var FiveDay = "Five Day: " + document.getElementById( "5dayDate").value; 

  var TwentyDay = "Twenty Day: " + document.getElementById( "20dayDate").value;

   document.forms["myform"].submit(); 

cal_single.addEvent(subject, foilFirst + foilLast + foilEmail, '', originDate, originDate);
}
</script>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO Ronald .I'm not familiar with this library, but idea is that you must create function to get the values from inputs and set it into your file in the same step - everything on button DOWNLOAD...

Comment: Thank you! A set of fresh eyes always help make the obvious so clear! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not need the form most of the other events you are tying to. I just clicked through to the component you are using and they have a clear example on usage.

I edited your code so that it minimally works. You should be able to tweak the functionality from here and see what the usage pattern needs to be like.

See below

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgithub.com/nwcell/ics.js/master/ics.deps.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Select FOIL Owner</legend>

    Handler:
    <p>
      <select name="category">

        <option value="Ronald">Ronald</option>
        <option value="Thomas">Thomas</option>
        <option value="Elizabeth">Elizabeth</option>

      </select>

    </p>

  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>FOIL Request Information</legend>
    First name:
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="firstname" name="fname" />
    <br>Last name:
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lname" />
    <br>Email:
    <br>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" />
    <br>Phone:
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" />
    </form>


    <br>


    <div>
      Title:
      <input type="text" name="summary" id="summary" />
      <br>
      <br>Origin Date:
      <input type="date" id="originDate" name="originDate" />
      <br>

      <br>

      <div>

        5 Day Reminder Date:
        <input type="date" id="5dayDate" name="FiveDay" />
        <br>

      </div>
      <br>

      <div>

        20 Day Reminder Date:
        <input type="date" id="20dayDate" name="TwentyDay" />
        <br>

        <br>Description:
        <br>
        <textarea id="description" name="description"></textarea>
        <br>Location:
        <br>
        <input value="New York" id="location" name="location" />


        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="wrap">
          <a href="javascript:doit()">Single Event</a>
          <br>
          <br>



        </div>

        <script>
          // Demo

          function doit() {
            var cal_single = ics();
            var subject = "Title: " + document.getElementById("summary").value;

            var foilFirst = "Contact First Name: " + document.getElementById("firstname").value;
            var foilLast = "Contact Last Name: " + document.getElementById("lastname").value;
            var foilEmail = "Contact Email: " + document.getElementById("email").value;
            var foilPhone = "Contact Phone: " + document.getElementById("phone").value;

            var description = "Description: " + document.getElementById("description").value;
            var location = "Location: " + document.getElementById("location").value;

            var originalDate = document.getElementById("originDate").value;

            var FiveDay = "Five Day: " + document.getElementById("5dayDate").value;

            var TwentyDay = "Twenty Day: " + document.getElementById("20dayDate").value;


            cal_single.addEvent(subject, foilFirst + foilLast + foilEmail, '', originDate, originDate);
            cal_single.download()
          }
        </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You're solution smacked me in the head - DOH!